# HTTP download in hidden iframe........... but! I need to set a Auth HTTP header in the IFRAME SRC

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-headers

Gosh, this is one of those things that I have been beating up for 2 days. I am trying to **pull a file down via Javascript in a hidden IFRAME**.

- I got the file name
- I got the endpoint (i.e.,
  http://www.com/images/myimage.png )

But I need to do the above in a hidden IFRAME. This is what I got, please feel free to join me while I scratch my head some more.

```
 var url='http://www.com/images/myimage.png';
 var _iframe_dl = $('<iframe />')
     .attr('src', url)
     .hide()
     .appendTo('body');
```

This works great. The Content-Disposition is *"application/octet-stream"* but unfortunately, I need to set this ...........

HTTP OAUTH HEADER (Below is fake token ):

**"Authorization:Qn2zBQratrwFzqPScCMd"**

Comment: Could you explain why it has to be in a hidden iframe? Since you could just ajax the data with any header you like and then just place the file in the iframe after.

Comment: Hi Shilly thanks for reply. This is a file manager JS widget that if you "right-click", then click "Download", it will down load a file. I do not want to open up another tab or change the self.location

Comment: I looked at AJAX, but then there is overhead and plus, I need to deal with binary response Types.

Comment: Overhead? And you can ajax any type of file. The iframe doesn't have the same access rights as the parent frame, so getting the header set correctly will probably be more difficult.